How to delete all files except the last day files in Linux?
Suppose these are my files:
file1 ==> 2024/07/10
file2 ==> 2024/07/9
file3 ==> 2024/07/9
file4 ==> 2024/07/8

I'm going to delete all files, except files which create date is yesterday (2024/07/09 is yesterday).
I know this find command, but I only know how to delete files older than N days, which keeps today files and yesterday files:
find . -mtime +2 -delete

Update2
I think it might be a way:
yesterday="$(date -d 'yesterday' '+%Y-%m-%d')"
while read -r file
do
    if [ "$yesterday" != "stat $file -c %y | awk -F ' ' '{print $1}'" ]
    then
        rm -vf "$file"
    fi
done < <(find . -type f)


I mean: if stat {} -c %y != $yesterday, then delete the file. But that deletes all files:(

what was the date/time when you ran the commands?

@jhnc I ran it just now (July 11).

so deleting files for July 11 seems correct. they are not "yesterday"

@jhnc yes, but there are some problems. 1) July 9 file is there ls -lh. 2) Not all July 10 files are there.

yes, that is a problem with the definition of -mtime 1 that I raised in the comments to the answer - it means the time interval >=86400 seconds ago and <2*86400 seconds ago

if you are using GNU find, simple fix is to specify -daystart option so that calculations run from midnight-midnight, not the current time

Yes, you're right. I'm thinking to use stat and create a variable like yesterday=$(date ...), then if create date is not yesterday, delete it. I'll be back ASAP I find it

@jhnc I edited the update2 with a solution (maybe), but it's not working yet:(

since you seem to have GNU utilities, you can try: find . -daystart -type f ! -mtime 1 -ls (and without !) to see they give the selections you want

@jhnc it seems without ! is showing the excepted result, and with ! is deleting all the files which are not for yesterday. Thanks. Please write it as an answer if you could.

Standard find uses 86400 second intervals from when the program started, to compute n in -mtime n / -mtime +n / -mtime -n.
It appears the question is looking for intervals based on the calendar date.
It is not obvious to me how to do this portably in a simple way. However, if GNU find is available, it has a -daystart option that allows for precisely this:
Files to keep:
find . -daystart -type f -mtime 1 -print

Files to delete:
find . -daystart -type f ! -mtime 1 -print


Note that -mtime checks last modification timestamp, not file creation. These are likely to be different. There isn't a standard find option to check file creation timestamp (and filesystems may not store it). However, GNU find has an option that may help -newerBt:
-newerXY reference
      Succeeds if timestamp X of the file being  considered  is  newer
      than timestamp Y of the file reference.  The letters X and Y can
      be any of the following letters:

      a   The access time of the file reference
      B   The birth time of the file reference
      c   The inode status change time of reference
      m   The modification time of the file reference
      t   reference is interpreted directly as a time

      Some combinations are invalid; for example, it is invalid for  X
      to  be t.  Some combinations are not implemented on all systems;
      for example B is not supported on all systems.  If an invalid or
      unsupported  combination  of  XY is specified, a fatal error re‐
      sults.  Time specifications are interpreted as for the  argument
      to  the -d option of GNU date.  If you try to use the birth time
      of a reference file, and the birth time cannot be determined,  a
      fatal error message results.  If you specify a test which refers
      to the birth time of files being examined, this test  will  fail
      for any files where the birth time is unknown.



I'm going to delete all files, except files which create date is yesterday

This will match all files except those created Yesterday.
find . -type f ! -mtime 1 -printf '%BF %p\n'  # or %CF
#              ^
#            not Yesterday

Note that files created Today will match as well as files created before Yesterday.
Replace -printf ... with the action you want when you are satisfied that it matches the correct files.

looks promising! I've gone down the rabbit-hole of trying to portably calculate "yesterday" where it runs from 00:00:00 to 23:59:59 rather than between 86400 and 2*86400 seconds ago (which is what the -mtime 1 computes)

@jhnc Isn't the fractional part ignored? Jeez, find's time calculations are just bonkers. find . -type f -printf '%CF %p\n' | grep ^2024-07-09 is a bit simpler but leaves the comfort of not having to parse the output.

I was planning to use -newer with two files created with appropriate touch timestamps but then realised I didn't know how to portably calculate date for "yesterday" :-) If we don't care about that, GNU find has -daystart, etc

@jhnc I'm looking forward to your version. :-) Now it's time to hit the sack.
